# Set a cookie in playwright

Tags: playwright

I have a pop up "Do you agree to Cookies" window on a site I am testing and I need to bypass this, the best way I have found out is to insert a cookie beforehand, but I cannot find out how to do this on Playwright - I have done some searching around but can't find a definitive answer for what i am after, essentially the cookie just needs to fire before the URL is hit so the scream doesn't appear.

Playwright cannot see the frame unfortunatley, otherwise I would just click it..

Comment: Can you add programming language and target url?

Comment: Hi @MeT apologies yes i am using javascript, i can't give the url unfortunately as it's a secured test env

Answer (score 2):

Use [browser_context.add_cookies](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-add-cookies).

I am going to assume the domain of the site where you want to add cookies is **[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)**, and the cookie=value pair is **hello-world**.

If you are using asynchronous python:

```
chromium = playwright.chromium
browser = await chromium.launch(headless=False, devtools=True)
context = await browser.new_context()
await context.add_cookies([{'name': 'hello', 'value': 'world', 'domain': 'www.google.com', 'path': '/'}])
```

If your code is synchronous

```
chromium = playwright.chromium # or "firefox" or "webkit".
browser = chromium.launch(headless=False, devtools=True)
context = browser.new_context()
context.add_cookies([{'name': 'hello', 'value': 'world', 'domain': 'www.google.com', 'path': '/'}])
```

Comment: Thanks Charchit, is there a js alternative do you know? I've tried the above urls instructions but not getting anywhere with it :(

Comment: @busyguy, similar api is available for node js, JAVA and .NET. For nodejs: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-add-cookies . I suggest spending some time with playwright documentation page : https://playwright.dev/docs/intro